# Problems Reading json data return to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json return data, I am unable to access any of the data within the JSON, I have used this method before and it works, but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here.

the data["json"] will print out the json data but data["default"] or data.default will not print out the individual information within the json data.

JSON: {"default":"y","mqdefault":"y","hqdefault":"y","sddefault":"y","maxresdefault":"y"}

the jquery is:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "response.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".the-return").html(
                "default: " + data["default"] + "<br />mqdefault: " + data["mqdefault"] + "<br />hqdefault: " + data["hqdefault"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
            );

            //alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try to use _$.parseJSON(data)_, and then _data.default_ ?

Comment: There's no way we can help you with this, you have to log the `data` and see what you have using console.log etc.

Comment: What's `data.json`? That doesn't appear in your sample JSON. Or is JSON a top level property and what you've listed is a nested object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i had run into a similar type of situation where i was getting a json data in the response from my server that i was able to print in log, but i was not able to access its variables.

Later i found out that this was because the data that was being received in the callback success function was not actually a json value. You might need to check if it is actually a json or else you can parse it to a json.

Possibly your data is not a proper json format due to which you are not able to access data["default"]

Comment: Yea, checked the array I was creating before encoding to json and that was the issue, when encoded it wasn't in the proper json format. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction